QField Error on virtual layer
I´ve build a little project with a point layer and a virtual layer. I´ve import the layer from the procet to the virtual layer and add some code. This will create a buffer zone around my point layer. Symbology on point layer won´t shown by zoom in and the point is out of map. With virtual layer, it will work.

Now on QGIS all is fine, but when I package it with Qfield sync and an upload it manually to my Android for QField, I´ve got an error with virtual Layer.

Link to my Project on Google
What can I do to fix this?

The layer punkteWithBuffer is loaded in the project so you shouldn't embed it in the virtual layer (top section).
